# ui-router views and ng-animate work only with attributes, but not classes

Tags: angular-ui-router, ng-animate

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="slide1" ui-view="slide1"></div>
<div class="slide2" ui-view="slide2"></div>
```

And this CSS:

```
[ui-view].ng-enter {
    /* ... */
}

[ui-view].ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
    /* ... */
}
```

This works, but if I change `[ui-view]` to either `.slide1` or `.slide2`, it doesn't work. E.g.:

```
.slide1.ng-enter {
    /* ... */
}

.slide1.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
    /* ... */
}
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason when the `<ui-view>` element is used animations won't work. However if you mark your router container element with the `ui-view` attribute rather than with a `<ui-view>` element animations will work.

As an attribute of an HTML element works:

```
<div ui-view class="slide1"></div>
```

As an stand-alone element doesn't work:

```
<ui-view class="slide1"></ui-view>
```